# What's up with [commentaries]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I'm assuming that [commentaries](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commentaries) is supposed to be used for questions that relate to a specific peirush, or Mefarshim in general.

If you go to the tag, it doesn't seem that way.

Is the tag being used properly, or should it be cleaned up a bit?

Comment: See discussion at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=31459749#31459749 et seq.